# Calculate Sum in DAX

Tags: filter, sum, dax

Both the columns are in the same table. I've been trying with `CALCULATE(SUM)`
but how do I apply the OR condition?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `CALCULATE`?
I've assumed your table is called `Table1`.
`DAX` works differently from Excel formulas. The filtering needs to happen outside `SUM` with calculate.

```
Calculation =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table1'[CC_BASE_AMOUNT] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Table1'[CC_ACCOUNT] ),
        [CC_ACCOUNT] IN { "10110101", "10110201", "10110303", "10119701", "10119901" }
    )
)
```